# Memory Leak in Foundation NSCFString. NSString created and Released. Still Leaks

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am getting a leaked NSCFString from this code. I understand it has to do with the NSString however, I do not understand how the leak is happening. Thanks for your help in advance...

```
-(void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark{

    NSString *pTitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:placemark.title];

    mapView.userLocation.title = pTitle;
    [pTitle release];


}
```

Comment: are you checking the leaks on Instrument??

Comment: yes, I am running a device and checking leaks in instruments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you also leaking a map view? In that case the reported leak of this string is just by extension of the leaked map view.

Most often the *most leaked* object is not the culprit. The culprit is usually a single object holding on to a dozen of the *most leaked* object.

Also, you can cut down your code to:

```
-(void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark {
    mapView.userLocaltion.title = placemark.title;
}
```

No need doing memory management when not needed :).

Comment: I changed my code and checked my mapView releases. The leak is still there however now it is coming from MapKit.

I am setting the property to nil and releasing the iVar in dealloc.

-(void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
 self.mapView=nil;}
- (void)dealloc {
 [_mapView release];
    [super dealloc];}

Comment: @SteveBay22 - There is also the chance that the leak is in Apple's framework, it happens from time to time. Double check, and file a bug at bug http://report.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of bugs in Apple's Framework buddy.. don't worry about the leaks from framework.

Just follow the rules at your side. For every `alloc`, `copy` or `retain`, there must be a corresponding `release`.

Also iOS handles `NSString` in a quite different way..So it is better to stick with the rules.

hope it helps..